# Resume workflow with cadence

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

While executing tasks, if there is a failure would like to define configuration to retry after certain interval and resume from the task that failed. Is it possible to implement the resume option?

Comment: There are multiple types of failures. You want to specify which exact failure you want to deal with. For example a large number of failures don't need to be explicitly handled as they are already taken care of by the Cadence itself.

Comment: Business failures is one of the scenarios. Second scenario is when a rest service call fails within a task/activity due to downstream unavailability, would like to retry and resume after certain delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for resume option for the business failures in the majority of the cases.

The common pattern is to keep retrying until the downstream dependency is available. This is possible as Temporal/Cadence doesn't have system imposed limit on the duration of the activity retries. If the downstream system can be down for days it is OK to keep retrying for days.

If for some reason you want to stop retrying after some time and then resume it on an external signal then can be implemented as part of the workflow logic which on certain types of activity errors workflow sleeps for an external signal to resume.

**Update:** I added a [sample](https://github.com/temporalio/samples-java/tree/main/src/main/java/io/temporal/samples/retryonsignalinterceptor) of an interceptor that stops activity retries until a signal to fail or keep retrying is received.

Comment: Thanks Maxim for the clarification. Can you point me to any example for the second point you mentioned about resuming workflow based on external signal.

Comment: Basically workflow would block until the signal is received. The exact mechanism depends on the SDK. In Java it would be Workflow.await call or Promise.get in Go it is usually select on a signal channel and a timer.